# How can I locate code in IDEA plugin by FilePath and LineNum?

Tags: intellij-plugin

In IDEA plugin, Can I implement the functionallity just like 
[clicking the item in debug thread stack and jump to corresponding location in IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYfT5.png) ? I have full className and line Numbers. I can't find it in the official sdk doc or miss it.